# React "Uncaught TypeError: undefined has no properties"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently learning stuff in JavaScript and React and I face a problem I don't understand. For some reasons the code won't compile and I get this error. I think the problem is when I call the "getFact" function but I don't understand why !

I get this error : Uncaught TypeError: undefined has no properties

Here's my code :

```js
const App = () => {

  useEffect(() => {getFact();}, []);

  const apiLink = "https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random";
  
  const [value, setValue] = useState('nothing');

  const getFact = async () => {
    const data = await fetch(apiLink);
    const dataJson = await data.json();
    setValue(dataJson.value);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 onClick={this.getFact}>New Fact</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I hope you'll be able to help me !
Thanks

---

EDIT

I now know wasn't supposed to use "this" but may I ask why I've seen some examples where "this" is used and everything works fine ? for example :

```js
  handleClick() {
    this.setState(state => ({isToggleOn: !state.isToggleOn}));}

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.state.isToggleOn ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}</button>
    );
  }
```

Comment: For your updated question, if you're using a Class Component, you will need to use `this` for the member functions. The `render()` function is a part of React Class Component and in the functional component, it's the function itself with `return` statement.

Comment: Ohhhh yes ! I'm so stupid but yes it all makes sense !

Comment: Hi, you might get a [question ban](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans), if you don't start accepting answers for your questions. Please take care.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using a functional component, where `this` is non-existent. You just need to change to `getFact` and it should work. Here's a working code:

```js
const App = () => {

  useEffect(() => {getFact();}, []);

  const apiLink = "https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random";
  
  const [value, setValue] = useState('nothing');

  const getFact = async () => {
    const data = await fetch(apiLink);
    const dataJson = await data.json();
    setValue(dataJson.value);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 onClick={getFact}>New Fact</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```